# How to download zip with php without messy code

Tags: php, linux

I want to download xxx.zip in my linux server.

And I got the code from php offical web site. The url is

```
http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php
```

I have set content-Type: application/zip. But unlucky, when executing the download.php, I got messy code in firfox or chrome browser.

My linux charset and browser charset are both utf-8.

Here is my download.php code:

```
<?php  
 $file_name = "xxx.zip";        
if (!file_exists ($file_name)){    
   echo "file is not exist";    
   exit();    
} 
else{    
header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.basename($file_name).'"');
header('Expires: 0');
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Pragma: public');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file_name));    

readfile ($file_name);    
exit;    
} 
?>
```

Compress xxx.zip code is:

```
<?php
$fileArr={1.jpg,2.jpg,3.jpg};

$fpName="xxx.zip";

$zip=new ZipArchive();
$zip->open($fpName,ZipArchive::CREATE);
foreach($fileArr as $file)
{
  $zip->addFile("files/".$file,basename($file));
  //$zip->renameName($file,$fileChName);
}
$zip->close();
?>
```

However, I can download xxx.zip file with xftp from linux server, and decompressing xxx.zip successfully in my windows desktop.

Comment: What's the question?

Answer (score 0):

```
$file_name = "xxx.zip"; 
header("Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate");
header("Expires: 0");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" .basename($file_name)."\"");
header("Content-Length: " . filesize($file_name));
header("Content-Type: application/zip;");
readfile($file_name);
exit;
```

This will work.

Comment: Hi, your code works fail. It also display messy code.

Comment: I just put this code in a method and call that method on click of a button and it works.

Comment: you can also download the zip file by passing full url in     <a href="{full-file-url-here}">Download Zip File</a> also.

Comment: <a href="xxx.zip">download</a> works ok. but this way can not be used in my project. I put your code to replace my code, unlucky, messy code again

Answer (score 0):

A function I have used several times to download files might be of use

```
function sendfile( $filename=null, $filepath=null ){
    if( file_exists( $filepath ) ){

        if( !is_file( $filepath ) or connection_status()!=0 ) return false;

        header("cache-control: no-store, no-cache, must-revalidate");
        header("pragma: no-cache");
        header("expires: ".gmdate("d, d m y h:i:s", mktime( date("h")+2, date("i"), date("s"), date("m"), date("d"), date("y")))." gmt");
        header("content-type: application/octet-stream");
        header("content-length: ".(string)( filesize( $filepath ) ) );
        header("content-disposition: inline; filename={$filename}");
        header("content-transfer-encoding: binary\n");

        if( $file = @fopen( $filepath, 'rb' ) ) {
            while( !@feof( $file ) and ( connection_status()==0 ) ) {
                print( fread( $file, 1024*8 ) );
                flush();
            }
            @fclose( $file );
        }
        return( ( connection_status()==0 ) and !connection_aborted() );
    }
}

$file_name = "xxx.zip";

if( file_exists( $file_name ) ) sendfile( 'somefile.zip', $file_name );
```

Comment: I have tested your code. It can not work. It is blank web site. Nothing appears.

Comment: Sorry - forgot to add the filename